# python3: how do i format 2 as 02

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

Apologies if this is a repeat question but,

what formatting commands do i need to use if I want a single digit number to be displayed with a zero in front?

i.e. the number '2' would be displayed as '02'.

[But, I do not want any value above 10 to have extra zeros in front]

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
>>> "{:0>2}".format(2)
'02'
>>> "{:0>2}".format(98)
'98'
>>> "{:x>4}".format(2)
'xxx2'
```

More info: [Common string operations](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html)

Comment: Taking my question further, for my general knowledge and future use, what do I do if i wanted to display 02.00? I tried using "{:0>2.2f}".format(2) but this strips off the leading zero?

Comment: The number after the `>` sets the minimum length of the resulted string. In this case it is 5 not 2. Use `{:0>5.2f}".format(2)`. If that helped please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if 0 < num < 10:
    return "0" + str(single_digit)
```

Comment: it's better to use formatting statements, IMO